# Software security Module/ toolkit replacing HSM for developing crypto functions

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, hsm

I worked and completed a PKI project which used a HSM for generating - storing keys and performing crypto functions. I used PKCS#11 to interface with our application for sigining/verifying and encryption/decryption. Our platform is windows.

Now we are looking to offer a low cost alternative solution by replacing the the HSM with a software security module. I must note here that i am aware of the drawbacks of not using a HSM. Its a trade off between security Vs Cost.

I found that Microsoft provides the Next Generation CryptoAPI (CNG), key store and certificate services. My senior management are not inclined to use open source software. I also found RSA and cryptomathic offering toolkits to perform software based solutions.

**Has anybody come across any commercial software security module tool kits to perform key generation, key store and crypto functions?**

Programming language - c/c++

Thanks

Raj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option should be to find a software PKCS#11 library. There should be several implementations on the market - I know that the company I work for sells one. That way you would still be able to switch back to a PKCS#11-compliant HSM and the necessary modifications to the application should be minimal.

Your other options are CryptoAPI or CNG from Microsoft or a toolkit from RSA, Cryptomathic or another vendor. That would probably require more work to rewrite the application - I can't really see any advantage to this option, except that CryptoAPI and CNG are free.

Comment: Are you referring "software PKCS#11 library" as wrappers around PKCS#11 cryptoki library? If this is the case, in what way do you think this is different from the functions which i have written for sigining/encryptition etc Can you please point me to some vendors on "software PKCS#11 library". Do these vendors provide key management functions as well or do i need to rely on the OS and another library for storing/accessing the keys? In what ways para 1 of your answer differ from para2. I am actually very confused here. Apologies, if i sound too ignorant.

Comment: PKCS#11 specifies an API (Cryptoki). You have been programming up against this API and presumably had a DLL that implemented this API with an HSM performing the operations. Several companies (including Cryptomathic, which is my employer) sell "software PKCS#11 libraries". A software PKCS#11 library would be a DLL implementing the PKCS#11 library but mapping the functions to a pure software implementation (and storing the keys in (encrypted) files). Key management can be done through the PKCS#11 API, but you might get a separate tool, too (depending on the vendor).

Comment: My second paragraph just relisted the options, you already knew of: other cryptographic APIs.

Comment: Looking around I actually can't find any vendors for software PKCS#11 libraries besides Cryptomathic (and that is hidden inside the product brochure for the PrimeInk toolkits...), but I am sure that there must be others.

Comment: Are you referring Keymanagement as generation,labelling and retrieving?  My doubt here is - i had the HSM to store the keys, will this 3rd party library take care of the key store and its security? I have been searching for a while now, has come across PrimeInk(Thanks Rasmus) and cryptokit from Arx. I am not sure whether there are any other vendors, if you come across please share.

Comment: I can't speak for other implementations, but I know the PrimeInk PKCS#11 library stores the key store encrypted on the hard disk with an AES key derived from the password. That is probably as good as it gets with a software library. If you do not need high throughput, another low-cost option might be a smartcard-reader with a smartcard. Those usually come with PKCS#11-libraries, too.

Answer (score 10):

You could use [SoftHSM](http://trac.opendnssec.org/wiki/SoftHSM), which is a pure-software PKCS #11 implementation. It is being used by the OpenDNSSEC project precisely to be swapped out in cases a real HSM is not available, so it might work for you too. However, it's BSD licensed, so I guess your management may not like it on that basis.

If you are looking for low-cost and yet commmercial (I'm not sure if you're specifically looking for something proprietary, which CryptoAPI is, or for something that is commercially supported, which CryptoAPI is not, unless you have a contract with Microsoft), rewriting your application to use the Win32 CryptoAPI seems the only viable option to me. RSA's toolkits are not cheap, in my experience.

Comment: Thanks Jack. You are right. If it is going to be case 2, i am planning to go with CNG as MS is phasingout cryptoAPI. Also Mozilla NSS has this virtual token of PKCS#11 implementation as well.

Answer (score 3):

I have a customer who used the software PKCS#11 implementation that comes with Mozilla's NSS as a drop-in replacement for the HSM.  They're on Linux using ruby-pkcs11, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: Hi Sander- This project has actually got over. But i am keen to look in to NSS. I looked at the example sources of Mozilla etc; But my problem is which version/ or from where - to download the NSS? Mine will be windows.

Comment: @Raj the home of the library is at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NSS, but they don't seem to publish binaries.  Fortunately, every copy of Firefox seems to have one!  You might find libsoftokn3.dll under the Firefox installation (I have no Windows machine handy to check).  I find I can just drop libsoftokn3.so into a trivial PKCS#11 program on my Linux host.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://www.openssl.org/related/kits.html for LSM-PKCS11. That could be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm testing a solution called [Vault from Hashicorp](https://www.vaultproject.io/) that is something like a SSM (Software Security Module) that can protect keys an make cryptographic operations. It has a server that can be used in "developer mode" (for testing and programming) and a very strict "production mode" that can be used in a final environment. The basic solution is Open Source, and if you need something more there are the "Enterprise Solutions" that are offering more methods of disaster recovery, backup, replication and more.

They are offering the solution with this exact words: 
"Manage Secrets and Protect Sensitive Data Secure, store and tightly control access to tokens, passwords, certificates, encryption keys for protecting secrets and other sensitive data using a UI, CLI, or HTTP API."

Download it and test it.